# Change <img> path when image is clicked. When other <img> is clicked reverse the previous ones path and apply new to the currently clicked one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, so I'm stuck a bit here and I'm very much noob at JS, so I thought it is okay if I ask you guys here.

What am I trying to do is the following:

1. Click on an `img icon` (3 icons total)
2. Display `div` with `text` and `img` bellow the `img icons`.
3. When other `img icon` is clicked, show related `div` to the related `img icon`.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!-- ICONS CONTENT -->
<div class="icons-holder">
  <div class="icon" data-rel="#content-a">
    <img src="media/images/icons/image-active.png" width="35%" id="first-icon">
    <h1>Индустриски<br>кетеринг</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="icons-holder">
  <div class="icon" data-rel="#content-b">
    <img src="media/images/icons/image1.png" width="35%" id="second-icon">
    <h1>Комерцијален<br>кетеринг</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="icons-holder">
  <div class="icon" data-rel="#content-c">
    <img src="media/images/icons/image2.png" width="35%" id="third">
    <h1>Организација<br>на настани</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- DIV WITH IMAGE AND TEXT CONTENT -->
<div class="services-content-holder">
  <div class="description" id="content-a">
    <div class="services-para">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service-img-holder">
      <div class="service-img">
        <img src="media/images/cook.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="description" id="content-b">
    <div class="services-para">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service-img-holder">
      <div class="service-img">
        <img src="media/images/cook.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="decription" id="content-c">
    <div class="services-para">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service-img-holder">
      <div class="service-img">
        <img src="media/images/cook.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So far I've done this thanks to Rory McCrossan providing the following JS script:

```
$('.icon').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
$('.icon').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setContent($(this));
});

// set content on load
$('.opis.active').length && setContent($('.opis.active'));

function setContent($el) {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.opis').hide();

  $el.addClass('active');
  $($el.data('rel')).show();
}
```

So, with this script I'm applying class `active` on the `img icons`, and here I want to use this as some kind of trigger in order to change the `<img src>` path with another JS script.

More specifically:

- Icon `img` that has class `active` - "take this path".
- When other `img` is clicked, give class `active` and - "take this path"

I tried to manipulate this script but couldn't manage how to achieve giving the images separated paths when clicked:

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
  var tradeoff = 'media/images/some-image.png';
  /** Reset images to original image **/
  $('img').each(function() {
    var $img = $(this);
    /** get the old original src **/
    var data = $img.data('oldsrc');
    /** only update if there is actually some value there **/
    if (data) {
      $img.attr('src', data);
    }
  });

  /** current image **/
  var $this = $(this);
  /** current href **/
  var src = $this.attr('src');

  /** only store if different from tradeoff value **/
  if (src != tradeoff) {
    /** store in image the old data **/
    $this.data('oldsrc', src);
  }
  /** show the tradeoff **/
  $this.attr('src', tradeoff);
});
```

I don't expect from you to solve my problem, but any kind of direction or solution would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.